# Trying to train a model on Jupiter and Google Colab. getting errors when trying to implement gradient calculations

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent, siamese-network

The errors I get are:

`ZipFile requires mode 'r', 'w', 'x', or 'a'`

or

`ZipFile.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'mode'`

or

TypeError: 'ZipFile' object is not callable

My Code:

```py
@tf.function
def train_step(batch):
    # Record all of our operations 
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:     
        # Get anchor and positive/negative image
        X = batch[:2]
        # Get label
        y = batch[2]
        
        # Forward pass 
        yhat = siamese_model(X, training=True)
        # Calculate loss
        loss = binary_cross_loss(y, yhat)
    print(loss)
        
    # Calculate gradients
    grad = tape.gradient(loss, [siamese_model.trainable_variables])
    
    # Calculate updated weights and apply to siamese model
    opt.apply_gradients(zipfile.ZipFile(grad, [siamese_model.trainable_variables], mode 
    = "w"))
    
    # Return loss
    return loss
```

```
def train(data, EPOCHS):
# Loop through epochs
for epoch in range(1, EPOCHS+1):
    print('\n Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, EPOCHS))
    progbar = tf.keras.utils.Progbar(len(data))
    
    # Creating a metric object 
    r = Recall()
    p = Precision()
    
    # Loop through each batch
    for idx, batch in enumerate(data):
        # Run train step here
        loss = train_step(batch)
        yhat = siamese_model.predict(batch[:2])
        r.update_state(batch[2], yhat)
        p.update_state(batch[2], yhat) 
        progbar.update(idx+1)
    print(loss.numpy(), r.result().numpy(), p.result().numpy())
    
    # Save checkpoints
    if epoch % 10 == 0: 
        checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix)

EPOCHS = 50
train(train_data, EPOCHS)
```

Errors show that the problem is coming from the train_step(batch) function when train invokes it.

I have also tried without `mode = "w"`, using just 'zip' when the brackets open and without the brackets for `siamese_model.trainable_variables` and I have tried
`import zipfile` or `import zip file from ZipFile` but it did not make a difference.

Comment: What is `opt`? Are you trying to write its result to a zip file? It seems like you're confusing the built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function with the `zipfile` module.

Comment: The first argument should be grad and models' variable. Please put them in a list and then  try again.

Comment: @hochae Could you please elaborate I tried using the square brackets on the model and gradient no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're confusing the built-in [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function with the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) module. The first is to combine multiple iterables and the second creates and reads compressed archives.

You probably want to use this:

```py
    # Calculate updated weights and apply to siamese model
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, [siamese_model.trainable_variables]))
```

Comment: opt is a variable, opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4) # 0.0001

Comment: I already tried this still gives me an error stating zipfile requires a mode

Comment: @KOR don't import anything from `zipfile`

Comment: Thank you!!!! going from what you iterated I restarted the kernel without the import statement and without the square brackets for the list and its working... before I just commented out the import statement and didn't work

Comment: @KOR glad to hear that! You probably overwrote the name `zip` with your import statement which is why it didn't use the correct function.

Comment: I appreciate it